# How Can I become a better WPF developer?

Tags: c#, wpf

For Quick learning WPF,I am following few books of WPF.But I don't know how to start it and which steps I have to follow to get Quick knowledge on WPF Programming with C#

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to think of interesting and useful projects. I suggest a charting library with data-binding support. You will learn many important notions like:

- Composing elements in a container
- Creating custom dependency properties
- Providing data-binding support for the list of points to draw (for example), using INotifyCollectionChanged interface
- Using fast rendering techniques to plot thousands of points (look for DrawingVisual class)

And most importantly: you will learn to create your own components that suit your own needs, instead of always relying on existing ones.

## Resources

**Interesting (must read !) resources that are not always documented in books:**

*WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern, Josh Smith*
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

*Writing More Efficient ItemsControls, Charles Petzold*
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd483292.aspx

*Using DrawingVisual Objects, MSDN*
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742254.aspx

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of tutorials on [WindowsClient.net](http://windowsclient.net/learn/), head over there and go through all of them. After that you might want to consider studying for the MCTS / MCPD in Visual Studio 2010 for Windows Development, that will certainly get you on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

"WPF 4 Unleashed" by Adam Nathan.

You don't need anything else.

Answer (score 1):

- Follow the [MVVM pattern](http://vimeo.com/9765330)
- Don't use code-behind unless you really have to
- Try and keep all your logic in your ViewModels
- Try to make your views dumb, so that they only concern themselves with presentation
- Create standard control styles and templates and push them into resource dictionaries so that most of the XAML in your Views is plain and simple
- Use (and study) a good WPF Framework such as [Caliburn Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) which will push you the direction of best practice
- Pick up a copy of [Pro WPF in C# 2010](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Pro-2010-Experts-Voice-NET/dp/1430272058/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1290070107&sr=1-1)

Answer (score 0):

Online tutorials. What helped for me was doing some WPF with F# tutorials that were based off Petzold's book. They started off doing everything programmatically without designers, and without xaml, and I learned xaml later.

But that is just me. There are a lot of online tutorials out there, that will probably be quicker, yet less thorough than books.

What books are you going through, and why are you having trouble starting at the beginning?

Comment: I am going through following three books:
Apress.Pro.C.Sharp.2008.and.the.dot.NET.3.5.Platform.4th.Edition.Nov.2007 
Pro WPF C# 2010
Pro-WPF-in-C-Sharp-2008-Windows-Presentation-Foundation-with-NET-3-5-2Ed

These are like My college study books and if I am going to read these books then m getting limited knowledge but I want to be a master in WPF. So help me or tell me will I read these books, is there any steps to follow..

Answer (score 0):

Nice article to start:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx